# php include_once reverse alphabaticly?

Tags: php

I'm currently using this piece of code to load news feeds to my webpage by adding a new html file for every article how can i include files in reverse alphabetical order, So that 2013-02-07 goes before 2013-02-08?

```
<?php 
   foreach (glob("news/*.html") as $filename)
{
    include_once $filename;
}  ?>
```

Comment: I would get a list of news files, put them in an array, sort your array then include.

Comment: as i sayd in your other question, why dont you use a cms or framework ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$files = glob('news/*.html');
rsort($files);
foreach ($files as $f) {
    include $f;
}
```

This actually does a reverse lexicographical sort (since the file names are strings), but that luckily works in this case since the dates are in highest to lowest magnitude order. More information: [rsort](http://php.net/rsort).

Note: I'm assuming your dates are formatted like YYYY-MM-DD. If they're formatted without leading zeroes, this solution will not work. You will have to extract the date from each file name, change it to some kind of intermediary type (unix timestamp, or a lexicographically sortable string) and then sort on that. For example `'2013-3-1' > '2013-12-1'` is considered true, but `'2013-03-01' > '2013-12-01'` is false.

Comment: Tnx works perfectly!!! And yes the dates are formatted YYYY-MM-DD for the sole reason of sorting files alphabetically, other wise I would have just named them by the news titles.